# Is there a way to make this formula run much faster?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, take

I have a formula with quite a few moving parts, taking data from very large datasets. It is so extensive that it is damn near crashing my computer I do not have the option of adding helper columns or editing the source data, and I would prefer not have to manually select the used cells because they are constantly being added.

Is there a good way to make this run faster that I am simply missing?

Here is the formula: `=IFERROR(TAKE(TAKE(SORT(FILTER('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!E:T,('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!G:G=BI2)*('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!B:B="MOL ")*('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!U:U>0)),16,-1,),1),,1),"")`

Comment: how many rows do you have in your data set?  limit the reference to a much smaller set than full column

Comment: so, i am writing this for someone not skilled in excel, so im trying to avoid them having to alter it. is there a way to make it only reference the cells that are used automatically or must it be manual?

Comment: Just set it to the largest the table will ever be.  I doubt it will ever get to 1m+ rows.  Start at about 10,000 rows larger than you think it will get.

Comment: simple solutions are often the correct ones. thanks @ScottCraner!

Comment: Besides Scott's remark: `TAKE(TAKE(,1),,1)` means the first cell only; you could use `@` instead.

Comment: And not sure if it makes a difference:
`=IFERROR(@SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!E:T,1,16),('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!G:G=BI2)*('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!B:B="MOL ")*('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!U:U>0)),2,-1,),"")`
The choosecols only takes columns E & T into the FILTER and therefore the SORT only sorts 2 columns of data. Not sure if that saves calculation, unable to test without sample data.

Comment: @P.b FILTER and SORT create intermediate arrays and thus decrease performance.

Comment: You can avoid the full-column references easily by designating your data as an official Excel table and, to build on @P.b 's solution, you can also avoid `IFERROR()` by using the _if_empty_ argument of `FILTER()` (populating that with `{"",""}` - since the `SORT()` is expecting a 2-column argument)

Answer (score 1):

You can try next suggestions.

First, you can replace 2 nested `TAKE` by `INDEX` to get the top left item (it's not the performance impact):

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        SORT(
            FILTER('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!E:T,
                ('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!G:G=BI2)*('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!B:B="MOL ")*('TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!U:U>0)
            )
            ,16,-1,
        )
        ,1,1
    )
    ,""
)
```

Second, considering the data source name, I can suppose what you search the max *number* in the `T` column. In this case you can use `XLOOKUP` and `MAXIFS` functions instead of `IFERROR`, `SORT` and `FILTER` combination:

```
=XLOOKUP(
    MAXIFS(T:T
        ,'TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!G:G,"="&BI2
        ,'TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!B:B,"=MOL "
        ,'TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!U:U,">0"
    )
    ,'TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!T:T
    ,'TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (9.22.23)'!E:E
    ,""
)
```

`FILTER` and `SORT` create intermediate arrays and thus decrease performance. `SORT` performs in O(n*log(n)) in the best, while `MAX` or `MIN` and `XLOOKUP` (in the worst) in O(n) each, totally in O(2n).

**Of cause, you need to limit the range** (don't refer whole columns).

Comment: Be careful with XLOOKUP and duplicates. It will return the first found value, but is that the correct one? (Also INDEX(range,1,1) can be replaced with @Range)

Comment: @P.b about duplicates: it's same as take the topmost sorted value. It can be more same values below. This means that XLOOKUP returns at least as good a value as `@SORT`.

Comment: @P.b @ is more efficient then 2xTAKE, but I guess it performs as fast as INDEX. But it looks more graceful, sure.

Comment: Xlookup is unsorted, there is a difference.

Comment: @P.b :-) SORT is unsorted too, no? "Right" SORT doesn't change the order of same items. XLOOKUP returns the first matched item. Is it not the same???

Comment: Sort, as used here sorts by 2 conditions. Xlookup doesn't

Comment: @P.b where? I see a single field to sort - #16. Anything else?

Comment: @P.b The `SORT` worksheet function allows to sort a range by the single key only: `SORT(array,[sort_index],[sort_order],[by_col])`

Comment: @rotabor `SORT()` is _not_ restricted to single-key sorting since both `[sort_index]` and `[sort_order]` can be array constants

Comment: @SpectralInstance Is it undocumented feature? Because I didn't find such information. In fact, SORT accepts the array constant as [sort_index], but takes the first item only as the sort key, as I tested.

Comment: @rotabor it's hardly undocumented, when there are so many examples online, e.g. [this](https://exceljet.net/videos/sort-and-sortby-with-multiple-columns) video transcript. My [testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f95oq.png) also illustrates it, and shows that a sort on a single key _is_ a stable sort.

Comment: @SpectralInstance I got it, but it's not related to the question.